# is order of execution of append_before_action filters same as their order of appearance in source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Does rails guarantee that the order of execution of multiple **append_action_filters** is same as the order in which these filters appear in the source file? For example,
I have a rails controller **problems_controller.rb**, a snippet from which is copied below.

```
append_before_action :force_sign_out_if_token_about_to_expire,  
only: [:get_create_problem_page, 
       :get_create_problem_page_v2,
       :get_solve_problem_page]

append_before_action :require_signed_in_user,  
only [:get_create_problem_page,  
      :get_create_problem_page_v2,  
      :get_solve_problem_page]
```

By using print statements, I can see that for all three actions listed above, **force_sign_out_if_token_about_to_expire** is executed before **require_signed_in_user**. But I couldn't find rails documentation which supports this observation. Though I could find documentation for filter chain ordering  [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) , for my application I would prefer to use the filters in the style listed above. Also, there is a problem I am facing if I try using the  filters as stated in documentation. I can elaborate on that if required.

Comment: the docu you referenced is from rails 2.3. i would not rely on that for anything...

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I couldn't find equivalent documentation for rails 4.2 though.